# Tomcat 8 JDBC Realm: change user's password

Tags: tomcat, jdbcrealm

I implemented a JDBC realm form authentication at my Tomcat instance. User names and their roles are stored in a database tables and administrator should assign a permanent passwords for users.
Is it possible to ask user change the password on the first attempt to log in, so that passwords were not prescribed by administrator but could be generated by users themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to implement this yourself. You could for instance add an extra column `isPassWordSet` to the user table, with default value `false`. Then, *after* a user logs in for the first time, using the password provided by the administrator, redirect to a page where he or she *must* provide their own password, allowing only users with `isPasswordSet=true` to the rest of the application. Once the user has finished this step, provided the supplied password is deemed valid, set `isPasswordSet` to `true` and one may proceed.

Comment: from where can I redirect the user? The one way I can do it is to use `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect( url )`, but I didn't find how can I get HttpServletResponse in custom Realm implementation.. please help..

Comment: You mean you want to extend RealmBase? I'm afraid that's not going to help. You could call a url from within the Realm to send the user to a second form but then you must still validate the user otherwise he or she will be sent to the initial login form. The form authentication is a Servlet Specification to guarantee portability across containers so there is no way to add extra form fields.

Comment: ... Still, once the user is logged in but hasn't yet changed the initial admin password, you can let your application enforce the user to change his password e.g. by some interceptor class that always checks whether the password is set. If not, redirect to the password form.

Comment: How about this: whenever I need to authenticate a user, I grab user credentials and perform `HttpServletRequest.login(name, pass)` method from within the servlet. Also, alongside the necessary user role, I add a "newcomer" role to him, so that I could see if his `isUserinRole("newcomer")` is `true` or `false`, and if `true` I would do `HttpServletRequest.sendRedirect( ChangePassUrl )` him to change the password and after that delete his "newcomer" role. Less database access this way.

Comment: Yes that's a nice concept, you'll be labeled `newcomer` as long as you don't fix your password. I assume you do the redirecting in a filter to deny `newcomer` access to the rest of your application?